# Reserve 16K sector in mcu flash with linkerscript at specific adress

Tags: arm, embedded, bootloader, stm32f4, linker-scripts

I'm creating a bootloader for STM32F429 with the gnu toolchain (9.2.1) and trying to reserve some flash memory for user data, shared by bootloader and application. I want to reserve the second of its first four 16K flash sectors for this, since they're nice and small: all other sectors are 128K.
The memory layout should look look like this:

```
ISR vector table : 0x08000000 (428 bytes)
padding          : 0x080001ac (15956 bytes)
-----------------------------
user data        : 0x08004000 (16K)
-----------------------------
bootloader code  : 0x08008000 (max 224K, for total of max. 256K)
```

I have modified ST's [linker script](https://github.com/timistof/linker-scripts/blob/master/STM32F429IITx_FLASH.ld) to look like this:

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 256K /* max. bootloader binary size */
    CCMRAM (rw)     : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
    RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 191K /* deduct 1K for NOINIT data */
    NOINIT (rwx)    : ORIGIN = 0x2002FC00, LENGTH = 1K /* NOINIT data will survive reset */
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
    /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
    .isr_vector :
    {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH

    /* Then comes user flash sector, make sure to get one of the first 4 that are 16K in size
    .user_flash :
    {
      . = ALIGN(0x4000)
      KEEP(*(.user_flash))
      . = ALIGN(0x4000)
    } >FLASH

    /* ... more sections below not shown here */
}
```

In my bootloader.cpp, I declare the user flash as follows:

```
__attribute__((__section__(".user_flash"))) const uint32_t user_flash[0x4000 / sizeof(uint32_t)] = {0};
```

However, in the debugger, the address of `user_flash` is not `0x08004000` as expected, but `0x0801b4e8`.

Removing the `__attribute__((__section__(".user_flash")))` from the declaration yields a different adress, proving the attribute has at least *some* effect.

Running `arm-non-eabi-objdump -h` on the .elf file confirms the (incorrect) adress of the `user_flash` section.
I have also tried declaring the section with `. = 0x08004000`, to no effect.

Another approach I tried is to place `.isr_vector` in its own 16K section, followed by a 16K section for the user flash and finally a (256-16-16) = 224K FLASH section. This produced a bogus binary that would hardfault.

What am I doing wrong here?

## Edit:

I've [tried](https://github.com/timistof/linker-scripts/blob/master/bootloader.ld) inserting a `.padding` section after `.isr_vector` to try to align `.user_flash` that way, but no matter what I do, `.text` and `.rodata` sections seem to always come immediately after `.padding`, even though they are declared after the `.user_flash` section.

Comment: Changed title and clarified desired memory layour.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* move the NVIC because we are running from 08004000 */
SCB->VTOR = (FLASH_BASE | 0x4000);
```